# rsync hangs after a few transferred files (Bash for Windows to FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows", from a Windows 10 Pro PC, to backup my media library to a FreeBSD server that acts as my NAS (it runs NAS4Free). This used to work perfectly but it recently stopped to work. Since I haven't changed anything on my side I reckon the change came from one of of the Windows Updates, not sure.

In any case, here's what happens. Just after a few files got copied over, the rsync transfer just hangs. I've let it run overnight to confirm and it just hangs for hours. When I manually kill the task by sending CTRL + C to the terminal I get an error message, some time goes on (about 30 secs) and the program stops:

```
arnaud@CLAVAIN:~$ rsync -arv --delete --no-compress /mnt/e/Music/ arnaud@nas4free.lan:~/pool1/lolilol/music
arnaud@nas4free.lan's password:
sending incremental file list
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/40. Finding Chico.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/41. I Am Carl Lucas.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/42. Crispus Attucks.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/43. Hideout.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/44. Cuban Coffee.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/45. Like a Brother.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/46. Cottonmouth's Clamp.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/47. Survival.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/48. Cottonmouth Theme.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/49. Luke Cops.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/50. Crushin' On Reva.m4a
ost/Luke Cage (Original Soundtrack Album)/51. Beloved Reva.m4a
^Crsync error: unexplained error (code 130) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.0]
[sender] io timeout after 60 seconds -- exiting
arnaud@CLAVAIN:~$
```

You can see where the ^C is, that's when I send the kill message. This is when the "error: unexplained error" and "io timout" errors show up.

I have tried an alternate command, `rsync -rltvzD --progress --delete`, but that produces the same error.

Is there anyway I could troubleshoot this better to understand what the problem is? Note that if I do this on a local drive (like a USB external drive) the rsync works just fine.

Comment: It appears that in respect of rsync, Windows Subsystem for Linux is defective in handling lists provided by rsync. This should be reported, and I have done.

Comment: Do you have the issue # on Github for this issue? There were several other issues opened with regards to rsync, all fixed, but those didn't solve my issue.

Comment: This looks like the issue discussed here on the WSL BashOnWindows Github Page:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2138

Comment: interestingly for me, if i ctrl-z background it, then `fg` foreground it, rsync will continue until it hangs on another file. it doesn't seem to be related to large files, and -W didn't resolve this for me.

Comment: same for me... any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this issue as well recently (as in yesterday), and what I found out, is that when I `rsync` without delta copy (using `--whole-file/-W` for whole file transfer), then everything works perfectly.

I know it is not the best solution, but a quick fix for now until it is patched.

Comment: This was the fix for me as well, works flawlessly with -W, even with -z -v etc

Comment: I can verify yet another case where this is correct. Ubuntu 18.04 under WSL on 1809. This should probably be the accepted answer/workaround.

Comment: This issue hit me today. It's still not fixed.

Comment: @Defcronyke Hello. It's 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. It only happens while rsyncing large files. I've come up with a workaround:

When a file stops transferring, I cancel it and then rsync whatever file stopped. For whatever reason, rsyncing the individual file always works. I usually have to do this for a few files before the original rsync goes through.

Super annoying, but I don't have any other solutions outside of not using the Ubuntu Bash under Windows 10, which would be disappointing.

My setup: rsyncing between Ubuntu running under Windows 10 and digitalocean's ubuntu server.

Comment: I've since given up on rsync under Windows Bash. I now use unison to sync the files and have had no more hangs.

Answer (score -1):

It is quite possible that the change in behaviour is due to a Windows Update and it changing the default permissions or disabling a feature during the update and not turning on properly again. Microsoft's solution for other errors is to disable and re-enable WSL.

If you are sure you haven't changed anything, and if it still doesn't work after disabling and re-enabling WSL from "Windows Features" you might want to post it as a bug/issue on Microsoft's github, 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues